# Devise scoped member routes issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing, rails-activestorage

I'm using devise for sign up and ActiveStorage for image upload. For the delete/purge function to work I have this route

```
  devise_scope :user do 
    scope module: :users do
      resources :registrations do
        member do
          delete :delete_image_attachment
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

But another place in my routes file I have this route

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {:registrations => "users/registrations" 
  }
```

It makes some of my pages not working. I have read somewhere that it's because registrations are declared two times. How can I make it work? 
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You could try something like `resources :registrations, only: [] do..`? It might work by not redefining the registration routes

Comment: It's working, thank you :-)

Comment: Cool, I added my comment as an answer to help others who may stumble upon this question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `resources :registrations, only: [] do...` that will create the parent route that you need without overwriting any of the routes provided by devise. Allowing you to make your nested routes :D